# Which of code will process faster PHP comments? Ideas?

Tags: php, comments, execution

What of this below example would for PHP execute in a shorter time? In case A or B? How to properly testing this?

Is faster processing in a short time with this:

CASE A:

```
/* -------------------------------------------------
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
------------------------------------------------- */
```

or with this?

CASE B:

```
/****************************************************
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
*****************************************************/
```

I've using this code for example for testing:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

$s = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<=10000000; $i++) {
/* -------------------------------------------------

------------------------------------------------- */
}
echo "1: ";
$r1 = microtime(true) - $s;
echo $r1;
echo "\n";

$s2 = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<=10000000; $i++) {
/* -------------------------------------------------
    some information inside commenting rules
------------------------------------------------- */
}
echo "2: ";
$r2 = microtime(true) - $s2;
echo $r2;
echo "\n";

$s3 = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<=10000000; $i++) {
/* -------------------------------------------------
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
------------------------------------------------- */
}
echo "3: ";
$r3 = microtime(true) - $s3;
echo $r3;
echo "\n";


$s4 = microtime(true);
for ($i=0; $i<=10000000; $i++) {
/****************************************************
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
    some information inside commenting rules
*****************************************************/
}
echo "4: ";
$r4 = microtime(true) - $s4;
echo $r4;
echo "\n";

$result = array('1 without text', $r1,
      '2 single line', $r2,
      '3 multiline separator', $r3,
      '4 multiline starred', $r4);

echo min($result);

echo '</pre>';
```

Result can be vary due to execution and memory manipulation. In mostly case, my case result is CASE B.

What about are your results?

Comment: You should get no variation once the bytecode has been generated (ie before execution actually starts)

Comment: if it matters, then your doing something wrong

Comment: @MarkBaker I was thinking that ... but then how does reflection class work when getting the doc blocks, by referencing the precompiled source?

Comment: Why case B is faster than case A?

Comment: Docblock comments are included in the bytecode (that's why doctrine, symfony2, etc use them) whereas non-docblocked comments are not, but compilation to bytecode has already taken place at that time so it shouldn't affect execution speed, only memory usage

Comment: Okay, think a statistical, you have a huge bunch of code with huge bunch of docblocks and want to measure execution of comments to make sure which docblock would process in shorter time.

Comment: @MarinSagovac Reorder the tests and see if you get the same results... I think bu the time your second test happens all of the resources php is going to need have been allocated

Comment: I believe that OptimizerPlus with PHP 5.5 apparently strips docblocks from the bytecode by default, but can be configured to retain them when required: cf `zend_optimizerplus.save_comments` and `zend_optimizerplus.load_comments` settings in php.ini

Comment: On every results is very very different, it's compiled in bytecode so this can be irrelevant my testing. I know that I'm wrong.

Comment: @MarkBaker interesting tipp! I didn't realize it. My version is `5.4.9`

Comment: http://devincharge.com/docblock-docblock-wherefore-art/ and http://blog.feryn.eu/2010/12/zend_soap_autodiscover-eaccelerator-causes-trouble/ for reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY RESULT:   **DOCBLOCK** win.

### RESULTS:

8 ms  faster than slowest CASE A. Docblocks on millions comments takes about 237 ms.

### COMPARISONS:

```
 CASE     SECONDS:    EXAMPLE CODE:
 A:       0.304       /******************** comment ********************/
 B:       0.343       /*------------------- comment ---------------------*/
 C:       0.293       /*                    comment                    */
 D:       0.237       /**
                       * comment
                       */

 [millions of comments in separated files]
```

### Results of testings:

For CASE A:

```
/******************** comment ********************/

0.31907296180725
0.31833505630493
0.31972694396973
```

For CASE B:

```
/*------------------- comment ---------------------*/

0.2824490070343
0.28207182884216
0.28176498413086
```

Results in ms (miliseconds). I've ordered of code of execution or loading as separated file, a results are same so make sure that are testing properly.

**RESULT:**

So, on a CASE B is faster than CASE A if I have 1 million comments on a one file. **Case B** is faster for average 3 ms.

**FASTER THAN CASE B AND C:**

I've tested with this new:

```
/*                    comment                    */

0.27404689788818
0.27441191673279
0.27490782737732
```

---

So in my projects will never will be like CASE A or B and C too.

Finally D, **DOCBLOCK**:

And finally, **DOCBLOCK** is fastest:

```
/**
 * comment
 */
[NL]

0.23765897750854
```

Comment: I think the difference you may be noticing here is due to "/**" being interpreted as docblock comments, which in turn have a special meaning in Reflection. Try "/**----" vs. "/******".

Answer (score 1):

A comment is eliminated at lexing time, and thus their contents are irrelevant, especially in your benchmark above.

If two multi-line comments in a file are the same amount of bytes in total, they'll have the exact same effect on PHP. A comment that's larger will take more time to be processed in full, and then discarded, but still, we're talking about the lexing phase, which is so fast that you'll need a single comment that's gigabytes in size vs. a few bytes comment to notice a difference.

If you use an op-code cache (or simply run PHP 5.5+ as an Apache module or FCGI, where there's now a built in op-code cache), you'll see zero difference, since the idea of an op-code cache is to make it so that lexing and parsing is done only once.

If you insist on doing a test, at least do it from the outside - create a file with contents like:

```
<?php
$start = microtime(true);
include 'test.php';
echo microtime(true) - $start;
```

And replace 'test.php' with the name of whatever file you'll be testing. Make sure to run every test file a few times, since the differences are insignificant anyway. To make the differences more apparent, you might want to generate millions of comments for that file. Here's an example generator:

```
<?php
$file = '<?php';
for ($i=0; $i<1000000; $i++) {
    $file .= "/* comment */\n";
}
$file .= '?>';
file_put_contents('test.php', $file);
```

You shouldn't see any statistically significant differences with comments that are of roughly the same number of bytes.

Comment: Okay, but I need testing code that shows like an graph, that show really which comments example would faster than others. I really thinks than can be differently. If you have `SPACEBAR,* and /` i think it will be slower than if you use `* and /`

Comment: @MarinSagovac you would have to test from the outside... by the time your first microtime call is made the comments have been eliminated from the opcode.

Comment: When I `tail -f` of PHP comments it's look properly as end of line in a file: `/******************** comment ********************/` but it's likely limited for long lines of codes `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /casea.php on line 1000001`

Comment: It will execute if I put before `file_put_contents` this: `$file .= '?>';`

Comment: @Marin When you say "it will execute if", you mean "it will give this error if", or "it would NOT give this error if"? If you mean it WOULD give the error - remove that line! There's no need to close a PHP tag when your whole file is PHP. The code above does not add it intentionally.

Comment: I've tested it. Look at above code. I will testing on random PHP code with huge and bunch of comments. I think it will give me interesting results.